# For-loop over list of txt.files with if conditions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, merge, filelist

I am struggling with creating a for loop over all txt.files in a specific repository.
The goal is to merge all separately saved txt.files in a dataframe and add an ID-variable that can always be found in the txt-file-names (e.g., ID=10 for the file "10_1. Recording 01.10.2015 131514_CsvData.txt" )

```
txt_files <- list.files("Data/study", pattern = ".txt")
```

> txt_files
>    [1] "1_1. Recording 18.09.2015 091037_CsvData.txt"          "10_1. Recording 01.10.2015 131514_CsvData.txt"
>    [3] "100_1. Recording 02.10.2015 091630_CsvData.txt"        "104_1. Recording 22.09.2015 142604_CsvData.txt"
>    [5] "107_1. Recording 18.09.2015 104300_CsvData.txt"        "110_1. Recording 29.09.2015 081558_CsvData.txt"
>    [7] "112_1. Recording 21.09.2015 082908_CsvData.txt"        "114_1. Recording 29.09.2015 101159_CsvData.txt"
>    [9] "115_1. Recording 23.09.2015 141204_CsvData.txt"        "116_1. Recording 30.09.2015 110624_CsvData.txt"
>   [11] "117_1. Recording 01.10.2015 141227_CsvData.txt"        "120_1. Recording 17.09.2015 153516_CsvData.txt"

Read in and merge txt.files

```
    for ( file in txt_files){
    #  if the merged dataframe "final_df" doesn't already exist, create it
    if (!exists("final_df")){
    final_df<- read.table(paste("Data/study/",file, sep=""), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
    temp_ID <- substring(file, 0,str_locate_all(pattern ='_1.',file)[[1]][1]-1)
    final_df$ID <- temp_ID
    final_df <- as.data.frame(final_df)
  }
  #  if the merged dataframe does already exist, append to it
  else {
    temp_dataset <- read.table(paste("Data/study/",file, sep=""), header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
    #   extract ID column from filename
    temp_ID <- substring(file, 0,str_locate_all(pattern ='_1.',file)[[1]][1]-1)
    temp_dataset$ID <- temp_ID
    final_df<-rbind(final_df, temp_dataset)
  }
  return(as.data.frame(final_df))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `rbind` in a loop which leads to excessive copying in memory. Consider building a list of data frames and bind them together once with `do.call` outside of any loop. For this approach, `lapply` is a useful iterative alternative than `for` to build such a list of data frames as you avoid the bookkeeping of initializing an empty list and iteratively updating elements.

Also consider `paste0` with no separator argument and `gsub` to remove any characters from underscore to end of string for to extract ID.

```
setwd("Data/study")
txt_files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt")  

df_list <- lapply(txt_files, function(file)  
                  transform(read.table(file, header=TRUE, fill=TRUE),
                            temp_ID = gsub("_.*", "", file))   
           )

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```